# How to save @lob data using spring JPA repository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to save @lob(blob) data into DB using JPA repository.

I am trying something like below

```
User user = new user();
user.setProfile(<<BLOB DATA>>);
```

I want to set user profile as blob data and save to db

Comment: Why not make it as LongText and store it as string?

Comment: No its an xml data, so want to save as it .

Comment: XML is text... Why make it more complicated then that. You could also use a CLOB column. Also your code doesn't make sense, you are creating the user and the set the user to itself as the profile...

Answer (score -1):

we use **@Lob** to save the data in **BLOB** or **CLOB**

**Entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_LOB_TABLE")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long userId;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="PROFILE")
    private byte[] profile;
   //getters and setters

}
```

**JpaRepository**:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{}
```

**Service layer**:

```
userRepository.save(new User(1L,"hellodgasdgasdgasdgadsgas".getBytes()));
```

**output**:

**user_id,profile

1,BLOB**

Answer (score -1):

Why not use [Spring Content JPA](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/)?

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.11</version>
   </dependency>
```

> User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

   @Id
   private Long userId;

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   // if you have rest endpoints
   @MimeType
   private String mimeType = "text/plain";
```

> JpaRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{}
```

> UsersContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="usersContent")
public interface UsersContentStore extends ContentStore<User, String> {
}
```

This will also give you REST Endpoints (@ /usersContent) for handling your user's content.